# applying appsettings.json on azure webapp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I would like to set a key value pair under my App Settings on my Azure Web App.

I've tried many different ways to set it on my appsettings.json, however none of them is working.

Here's what I've tried:

test 1

```
{
  "APPSETTING_WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "E. South America Standard Time",
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

also

```
{
  "AppSettings:WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "E. South America Standard Time",
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

another test

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "E. South America Standard Time"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow. Web App's App Settings override the ones in your appsettings.json, not the other way around. These will not become visible there.

Comment: In fact, inspecting using Kudu, my App Settings variables on azure are actually environment variables. But anyway, I would like to set them directly from appsettings not through portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can set app settings in `appsettings.json`. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) for details.

The problem here is that you're trying to set `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`, which is a special setting recognized by Azure Web Apps. For it to be effective, it must be set as an Azure App Setting. The same is true for the various other special `WEBSITE_` settings (e.g. see s list [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings)).

Comment: So, I need to create a .deployment file and set like WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE=Eastern Standard Time ?

Comment: No, you need to use an **Azure App Setting** for it, per my answer. Nothing else will work.

Comment: if I just Include AzureAppSetting (like my third json sample) in the appsettings.json and define the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE it will work? I've looked for samples but could not find one.

Comment: No, that will not work. You need a true Azure App Setting

Comment: through portal you mean? There's no way to set that through any config file that will be published with my application?

Comment: Portal or Azure ARM API. Not through files.

Comment: So my custom settings (e.g. SomeApiUri) in appsettings.json wil not be copied to appsettings in azure?